# How would I specify a particular settings.py file in a wsgi file?

Tags: django, settings, wsgi

I'm a complete newbie to Python and Django but have a need to set up a website.

What commands/parameters would I add to a file of type *.wsgi that could specify a particular settings.py file in the context of Django?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango

if you're using a virtual environment, the path appended should correspond to your virtual environment.  You might also take a look at:

http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/03/improved-wsgi-script-for-use-with.html

which has a somewhat modified script that I prefer.

Answer (score 1):

In one of [these ways](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/).